# Integrate a multioption dropdown list in calculator Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, windows

I will try to explain this issue the better I can.

So I built a calculator using django. The user can put the desired input, and then he sees all the results in a table, only by pressing the button: 'select'. 
If the user only wants this result, the user see the result output in the table. 
However, if the user selects one of the options presented in the dropdowns, then the result should be different. Meaning that the dropdown list, has specific calculus. 
This is the part that I don't understand,I know that I have to use JS to this, but I don't know in which module this should be added.

[image]

Here is my code:

models.py

```
class CalcAnalyzer(models.Model):

    sequence = models.TextField()
    gc_calc = models.CharField(max_length=2000000)    
    person_of = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):# new
        if self.sequence != None:
            self.gc_calc = gc_calc(self.sequence) 
                    
        super(CalcAnalyzer,self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sequence 

class addcalc_1(models.Model):

    name_sequence = models.ForeignKey(OligoAnalyzer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    Option1_5 = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.Option1_5 = Option1_5(self.sequence)
        
class addcalc_3(models.Model):
    
    name_sequence = models.ForeignKey(OligoAnalyzer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    optional_3
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.optional_3 = optional_3(self.sequence)
```

views.py

```
def calc_sequence(request):

    sequence_items=Calanalisis.objects.filter(person_of=request.user)
    form=AddSequenceForm(request.POST)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=AddSequenceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile=form.save(commit=False)
            profile.person_of = request.user
            profile.save()
            return redirect('calc_sequence')
    else:
        form=AddSequenceForm()

    myFilter=SequenceFilter(request.GET,queryset=sequence_items)
    sequence_items=myFilter.qs
    context = {'form':form,'sequence_items':sequence_items,'myFilter':myFilter}
    return render(request, 'Add_Calc.html', context)
```

How can I insert this in the view.py? If the user selects the 5 or 3 box, the result should appear in the table bellow, if not, the result will stay the same.

Comment: This will require using JavaScript. If a user selects 5 or 3, you'll have to submit the form i.e. send a request to the server to get the new calculation in the response.

Comment: I haven't done it, that's way I'm trying to understando how to include it

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to do, can you upload a whole screenshot of the page and specify the intended result? You'll probably need some javascript to show results in real time.. i can help with that but i dont understand how this page is supposed to work

Comment: I altered the question description @Beikeni,thank you for the help

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want the values in the dropdowns to afffect the calculation. In this case you just need to make it so that the dropdowns have a name and a value that is included in the POST request. Then you can access their values from the view.

Comment: Can you confirm that this is what you want to do? You want to have the values from the dropdowns in the POST request so that you can execute calculations in your view?

Comment: yes that is what I want

Comment: @Sofia first you should try to elaborate your question a little so that it gets clear what you're trying to achieve, second as @Beikeni pointed out you can retrieve the value of the desired dropdown by using the `name` attribute inside your view, (i.e) `<option name='desired_value' value='some_value'> value </option>` this can be used to manipulate any result inside your view which you want to do ... you don't necessarily have to use js to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Sofia, hi!
To subscribe on the dropdown's events you need a piece of javascript.

### HTML and static files

So, you need to attach your new `script.js` file to your project. You can check what you need to serve static files (it's not a "one-click" solution, especially if you want to deploy your code for external users) [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

When your static file is ready you can include it in the front-end.

Let's imagine that you have `index.html` where your controls live.
Add the link to the file in your html (before closing `</body>` tag):

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/script.js"></script>`

### static.js

[This example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) shows you how to make an event listener and listen to the dropdown changes.

Use values from the selected options of your dropdowns to make a URL for the request. Ex. `/calc/api/?param=1`, so you will be able to catch `param=1` in your view and react properly.

dropdown example:

```html
<select id="param" name="here_name">
    <option value="">Select …</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

### API

Create an additional view to handle the requests that will be sent on events. Make it accessible with `urls.py`.

Use the proper URL to the endpoint in the javascript. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Fetching_data#fetch) you can find how to make requests from the JS to your Django back-end.

The param that was chosen will be in the `request.GET` of your view (if you've chosen GET method to send the data). So make a proper answer and send it back to the JS. You can use JSON format for this.

Parse the answer in the JS and change your page with updated information.